# MongoosJS Schema Non-empty String

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have Schema definition below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, index: { unique: true }},
    description: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

How to specify the `name` will not accept empty string.

Answer (score 5):

Setting the field as *required* will do the trick, like follows:

```
var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
    description: String
});
```

Another option is to add a validating regular expression, like follows:

```
var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, validate: /\S+/, index: { unique: true }},
    description: String
});
```

Comment: For optional string, I used: validate: /^$|\S+/